# Потоки и переключение контекста

Tags: асинхронность, многопоточность, сеть, c++

В основном я занимаюсь C++ network задачами, при этом использую модель одного потока для всех соединений или thread per CPU. Воспринимал как аксиому то, что такой метод работает быстрее, чем thread per connection. Но с недавних пор задумался.

Вот, к примеру, вызываем мы системную функцию в Windows (например, чтение из сокета):

1. Генерируется программное прерывание.
2. Находится адрес начала подпрограммы, который должен обработать эту функцию.
3. Идёт переключение на стек ядра.
4. Сохраняется состояние процессора.
5. Выполняется системная функция на уровне ядра.
6. Дальше, насколько я понимаю, зависит от блокирующего или неблокирующего вызова. Если вызов неблокирующий, то происходит обратное переключение на пользовательский поток, который вызвал прерывание, т.е. восстанавливается состояние регистров процессора и перключается на стек приложение. Если же вызов блокирующий, то пользовательский поток приостанавливается, а вместо него вызывается следующий готовый к выполнению (с учётом приоритета).
7. Если это был блокирующий вызов, то как только придут данные, нужный поток будет поставлен в начало очереди, и система продолжит его выполнение (с учётом приоритета).

Получается, что система в целом делает то же, что и делаю я в случае асинхронного программирования. Вместо какого-то контейнера объектов соединений используются потоки, также проверяется, есть ли активность, и нужный поток продолжает работу. В любом случае процессор не простаивает.

Вопросы:

1. Так в чём же преимущество на архитектурном уровне?
2. Корректно ли я представляю себе переключение контекста в случае остановки текущего потока и возобновление другого, это происходит в целом так же, как и программное прерывание, т.е. копируется состояние процессора и меняется указатель на стек? Или я путаю издержки на вызов системной функции с издержками на приостановку текущего потока и вызов другого?

Answer (score 1):

1. Модель на потоках проще для написания и более легка для отладки. Если есть немного постоянных подключений, то потоковая модель достаточно хороша. Асинхронная модель сложнее в написании, но при большом наплыве пользователей может дать большую производительность.
2. А кто его знает. У современных осей сколько оптимизаций... Но на самом то деле контекст переключается очень часто и ничего, все работает.

Answer (score 1):

При большом количестве соединений издержки на переключения между потоками могут вырасти в цене. В этом преимущество варианта реализации с конечным набором потоков.
С другой стороны, считаю изобретение своего велосипеда вредным. И рассуждаю следующим образом: вряд ли я напишу транспорт лучше, чем это сделали авторы ZeroMQ. Если же вынужден работать по какому-то стандартному сетевому протоколу, то использую библиотеку Poco, которой доверяю весь низкоуровневый менеджмент соединениями. И опять же, вряд ли я сделаю задачу лучше профессионалов, специализирующихся на задаче.